# Rails mailer Undefined local variable when filling template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I'm really really new to ruby on Rails, and would much appreciate your help!!

I'm trying to email a user after a post is created, with the information from the post. I am able to email the user once the post is created, but I cannot add the post's information into the mail template. If I try to use the posts variables in the email template, Rails returns "undefined local variable or method `micropost' for #<#:0x007fedf274d348>".

If someone could please help me?

This is my mailer:

```
    class Bicimensajeros < ApplicationMailer

    def post_email(usuario)
    @usuario = usuario

    mail(:from => "#{usuario.nombre} <#{usuario.email}>", :to => "#{usuario.nombre} <#{usuario.email}>", :bcc => "mail@gmail.com",  :subject => "Tu bicimensajero va en camino")

   end

end
```

This is the mail view:

```
<h2>Recibimos tu pedido y un bicimensajero va en camino</h2>

<p>Hola, <%= @usuario.nombre %>:</p>

<p>
¡Recibimos tu pedido con éxito!

<span class="content"><strong>Recoleccion:</strong> <%= micropost.pickup %></span>
<span class="content"><strong>Entrega:</strong> <%= micropost.dropoff %></span>

</p>

<p>Estamos en camino y recibirás una notificación por mail cuando tu envío haya sido completado.</p>
<p>Cualquier duda, estamos disponible en el chat de atención a clientes dentro de <a href="https//bicimensajero.com">bicimensajero.com</a></p>
<p>Por whatsapp al</p>

<p>Tu envío está asegurado.</p>

<p>Bicimensajero México</p>
```

Here is the micropost model:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :usuario
  after_create :send_email
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :usuario_id, presence: true
  validates :pickup, presence: true
  validates :dropoff, presence: true
  validates :precio, presence: true
  validates :telefono, presence: true
  validates :notas, presence: true
end

def send_email
   Bicimensajeros.post_email(self.usuario).deliver
 end
```

And my micropost controller:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_usuario, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @micropost = current_usuario.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Bicimensajero en camino!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      flash[:warning] = "No se solicito nada :("
      render 'estaticas/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:pickup, :dropoff, :telefono, :precio, :notas)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your action mailer template does not have a reference to an object named 'micropost'. The easist way to share an object between a mailer method and its corresponding template is to use an instance variable, like you are currently doing with the '@usuario' instance variable.  You should do the same with an '@micropost' instance variable, but your mailer method will need to know what to set it to.  So, give the post_email method a second parameter that will allow you to pass in a Micropost object.  Change your mailer to look like this:

```
class Bicimensajeros < ApplicationMailer
  def post_email( usuario, micropost )
    @usuario = usuario
    @micropost = micropost

    mail(:from => "#{usuario.nombre} <#{usuario.email}>", :to => "#{usuario.nombre} <#{usuario.email}>", :bcc => "mail@gmail.com",  :subject => "Tu bicimensajero va en camino")
  end
end
```

You'll also need to update your template to use the instance variable '@micropost' instead of the unknown local variable 'micropost':

```
<h2>Recibimos tu pedido y un bicimensajero va en camino</h2>

<p>Hola, <%= @usuario.nombre %>:</p>

<p>
¡Recibimos tu pedido con éxito!

<span class="content"><strong>Recoleccion:</strong> <%= @micropost.pickup %></span>
<span class="content"><strong>Entrega:</strong> <%= @micropost.dropoff %></span>

</p>

<p>Estamos en camino y recibirás una notificación por mail cuando tu envío haya sido completado.</p>
<p>Cualquier duda, estamos disponible en el chat de atención a clientes dentro de <a href="https//bicimensajero.com">bicimensajero.com</a></p>
<p>Por whatsapp al</p>

<p>Tu envío está asegurado.</p>

<p>Bicimensajero México</p>
```

Lastly, you need to ensure that the code invoking your mailer's post_email method, passes a Micropost object as its second parameter.  This is done in your Micropost model by passing 'self' as the second parameter:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :usuario
  after_create :send_email
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :usuario_id, presence: true
  validates :pickup, presence: true
  validates :dropoff, presence: true
  validates :precio, presence: true
  validates :telefono, presence: true
  validates :notas, presence: true

  def send_email
    Bicimensajeros.post_email( self.usuario, self ).deliver
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey man, thanks a bunch, that did it!! I know it was a rather simple issue, but for me its great to see my app working as it should. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `micropost` to your mailer, but it is used in your email view.  You need to pass a separate variable `micropost` in your `post_email` method to your mailer.

In your mailer, you should assign an instance variable `@micropost` as you did for `@usuario`.  Then, in your view, you will need to change `micropost` to `@micropost`.